# All subsequent insert statements ALWAYS enter the first insert statements in sqlite3 in objective C

Tags: objective-c, insert, sqlite

All subsequent INSERT statements ALWAYS enter the first insert statements in sqlite3 in objective C

For instance, if, when the table is empty I enter 'label = x' and 'score = y' , All other subsequent INSERT statements insert the same values for 'label' and 'score'.

Below is my code for my insert method:

```
- (void) insertDataInDatabase:(NSString*)label arg2:(double)score{

// setting up path to db file
sqlite3_stmt *insert_statement = nil;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,       NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDB.sqlite"];

// actually opening db and executing insert statement
if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    if (insert_statement == nil) {
    static char *sql = "";
    NSString *strSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO scores (label, score) VALUES('%@',%f)", label, score];
    sql = [strSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &insert_statement, NULL);           
    }

    if (sqlite3_step(insert_statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"INSEEEERT!!!");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"failed");
    }

}
sqlite3_clear_bindings(insert_statement);
sqlite3_reset(insert_statement);
sqlite3_finalize(insert_statement);
sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Please help?!

Comment: Where do you get label and score from?  Is the above your real code, or have you omitted some lines?

Comment: Lots of things wrong with the code -- shouldn't open/close on every access, insert_statement will always be nil in the if test (if you're showing us all the code), you should be using sqlite3_bind... instead of putting values directly into the INSERT statement.

Comment: You should check the return code from sqlite3_prepare_v2, there is no point in calling sqlite3_clear_bindings or sqlite3_reset when you're about to call sqlite3_finalize.

Comment: And note that you have to handle *all* possible error codes from SQLite.

Comment: Yeah thats all the code for that particular method. I'm going to try using the bind_text and bind_int functions